# SwiftUI NavigationItem dynamic data sending incorrect parameter

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I have what I thought was a simple task, but it appears otherwise. As part of my code, I am simply displaying some circles and when the user clicks on one, it will navigate to a new view depending on which circle was pressed.

If I hard code the views in the NavigationLink, it works fine, but I want to use a dynamic array. In the following code, it doesn't matter which circle is pressed, it will always display the id of the last item in the array; ie it passes the last defined dot.destinationId to the Game view

```
struct Dot: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let x: CGFloat
    let y: CGFloat
    let color: Color
    let radius: CGFloat
    let destinationId: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {

var dots = [
    Dot(x:10.0,y:10.0, color: Color.green, radius: 12, destinationId: 1),
    Dot(x:110.0,y:10.0, color: Color.green, radius: 12, destinationId: 2),
    Dot(x:110.0,y:110.0, color: Color.blue, radius: 12, destinationId: 3),
    Dot(x:210.0,y:110.0, color: Color.blue, radius: 12, destinationId: 4),
    Dot(x:310.0,y:110.0, color: Color.red, radius: 14, destinationId: 5),
    Dot(x:210.0,y:210.0, color: Color.blue, radius: 12, destinationId: 6)]

var lineWidth: CGFloat = 1

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack 
            Group {
                ForEach(dots){ dot in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Game(id: dot.destinationId))
                    {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(dot.color)
                            .frame(width: dot.radius, height: dot.radius)
                            .position(x:dot.x, y: dot.y )
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(width: .infinity, height: .infinity, alignment:  .center  )
            
        }

        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}


struct Game: View {
    var id: Int
    var body: some View {
    
        Text("\(id)")
    }
}
```

I tried to send the actual view as i want to show different views and used AnyView, but the same occurred It was always causing the last defined view to be navigated to.

I'm really not sure what I a doing wrong, any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it might seem that you're clicking on different dots, the reality is that you have a `ZStack` with overlapping views and you're always clicking on the top-most view. You can see when you tap that the dot with ID 6 is always the one actually getting pressed (notice its opacity changes when you click).

To fix this, move your `frame` and `position` modifiers *outside* of the `NavigationLink` so that they affect the link *and* the circle contained in it, instead of just the inner view.

Also, I modified your last `frame` since there were warnings about an invalid frame size (note the different between `width`/`maxWidth` and `height/maxHeight` when specifying `.infinite`).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var dots = [
        Dot(x:10.0,y:10.0, color: Color.green, radius: 12, destinationId: 1),
        Dot(x:110.0,y:10.0, color: Color.green, radius: 12, destinationId: 2),
        Dot(x:110.0,y:110.0, color: Color.blue, radius: 12, destinationId: 3),
        Dot(x:210.0,y:110.0, color: Color.blue, radius: 12, destinationId: 4),
        Dot(x:310.0,y:110.0, color: Color.red, radius: 14, destinationId: 5),
        Dot(x:210.0,y:210.0, color: Color.blue, radius: 12, destinationId: 6)]
    
    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Group {
                    ForEach(dots){ dot in
                        NavigationLink(destination: Game(id: dot.destinationId))
                        {
                            Circle()
                                .fill(dot.color)
                        }
                        .frame(width: dot.radius, height: dot.radius) //<-- Here
                        .position(x:dot.x, y: dot.y ) //<-- Here
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment:  .center  )
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Superb, thank you so much.

Comment: Apologies, thought I had done it. Done now.